# Handle "Enter" key on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, keyboard, handle, enter

I'm making an application, in this application I have edit text. I want when user write some text in edit text end then press enter button, I want it call some command. This what i have been done. This is work in ICS, but when I try on other device (Jelly Bean) it doesn't work.

```
inputViaTextChatbot.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                // hide the keyboard  
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                // process 
                getThis = inputViaTextChatbot.getText().toString();
                if (getThis!=null && getThis.length()>1) {  
                    try {
                    Log.v("Got This: ", getThis);
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    inputViaTextChatbot.setText("");  
                }
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
```

can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug that makes the `Enter` key not be recognized on several devices. A workaround to avoid it and make it work would be the following:

Create a `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` like this:

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener enterKey = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
      // Do whatever you need
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

Assuming your `View` is an `EditText`, for instance, you'd need to set it this way:

```
final EditText editor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Texto);
editor.setOnEditorActionListener(enterKey);
```

The final step to go is assigning the following attribute to the `EditText`:

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

This basically changes the default behavior of the enter key, setting it to the `actionGo` IME option. In your handler simply assign it the listener you've created and this way you'll have the `enter key` behavior.