# how do I handle enter on edittext in device?

Tags: android

I already have the code and it work in emulator but when I try to instal it on my device it didn't work? My android is **Jellybean 4.1**

```
edtNamaDokterPerasat.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                namaDokter = edtNamaDokterPerasat.getText().toString();
                Intent set = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DaftarDokter.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                set.putExtra(TAG_NAMA_DOKTER, namaDokter);
                startActivityForResult(set, 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I make it work on device? If I try to press enter on device, the result will be ENTER '/n', like go to next line below

Comment: what exactly u want to do at enter key ?

Comment: so on edit text you want to open new activity, but its just enter new line in edittext?

Comment: yes, like there's no setOnKeyListener on my code

Comment: i think u need to do -- edtNamaDokterPerasat.setOnKeyListener((new EditText.OnKeyListener() {..

Comment: no, I still can't do it, it work on emulator, but not on device

Answer (score 0):

I tried at google nexus device following code its works..

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);      
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                finish(); 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", "Enter"); //Optional parameters
                CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Well my device is android  4.2.1!! if u add logs onKey () are they printing??

Comment: hold on, I try to use external keyboard and it works? could it be because my android? I but I try with two device but the result still the same

Comment: what, you mean this? <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNamaDokterPerasat"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTeksNamaDokterPerasat"
        android:ems="10" />

Comment: Check this.. looks like known bug u have to overwrite 0 OnEditorActionListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834494/handle-enter-key-on-jelly-bean